# VS2017 Cant create Project - arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Creating a New Visual Studio Project:

```
File > New > Project
```

Causes an error:

> arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow

<sub>Answering my own question to help future developers...</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You will get this error if you installed VS2017 but didn't first install IE10 and related Hotfixes as per the requirements:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-system-requirements-vs

Install IE11/Edge and related Hotfixes then try a command-line /repair as per:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt720584.aspx or simply uninstall and reinstall.